# If a Munin plugin fails, nobody gets notified. Why is this so?

Tags: monitoring, munin

I've built a bunch of munin plugins that monitor various back-end services. If the metrics dip below thresholds set in `munin.conf`, we're notified by email. However, if one of these services goes down completely, the plugin will fail and nobody gets notified!

I've followed the module-writing guide and added an exit code and message:

```
 sys.stderr.write('Error connecting to %s: %s\n' % (name, e))
 sys.exit(2)
```

But this only appears in the log. Nobody is watching the log.

Is there a way to make Munin alert on a complete plugin failure?

Comment: I've not looked into munin plugins, but I would think could you just wrap the code that fails in a try..except and return a value below the threshold (a specific value for meaning service offline, e.g., -1) in the exceptional case.

Comment: Heh, I thought of returning -1 as well.

Comment: downside of that approach is it will screw up your averages.

Answer (score 0):

Are you open to alternatives? I believe that logcheck could solve your problem.

Comment: Or monit, sure, but I was hoping munin would do something smart.